# NHibernate orphan childs when assign new "Child" list to "Parent"

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I have a simple Class call it "Parent" and it contains list of child objects call it "Child".

There is a simple nhibernate mapping between them:

**Mapping for Child**

```
 // Child mapping
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="X" namespace="X">
  <class name="Child" table="Childs">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="Value"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Mapping for Parent**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="X" namespace="X">
  <class name="Parent" table="Parents">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <list name="Childs" lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="ParentId" />
      <index column="ChildIndex" />
      <one-to-many class="Child"/>
    </list>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So in my code

```
 IList<Child> NewChildObjectsList =....
 Parent.Childs.Clear();
 Parent.ChildObjectList = NewChildObjectsList;
 Update(Parent);
```

The problem is that when update parent, parent gets new child objects but there  exist "orphan child objects" whose parent id is not exist in the Childs table[ those  are old child object list elements]

In fact if i do and update just after the clearing list and after assign new child list there exist no orphan child objects...

```
 IList<Child> NewChildObjectsList =....
 Parent.Childs.Clear();
 Update(Parent); // ClearList then update
 Parent.Childs = NewChildObjectsList;
 Update(Parent); // Add new list then update
```

**What may cause this? And how to fix it? Any ideas?**

Comment: why do you set `Parent.Childs = NewChildObjectsList`? is clear not enough?

Comment: Well, that is my "business case"...Sometimes i have to add totally new child list to existing parent object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NH inserts its own implementation of IList to make its changetracking work. If you replace it with another implementation it would be lost. Most of the times it is bad practice to replace the implementation because the code doesn't know which implementation is in effect.

better do

```
Parent.Childs.Clear();
foreach ( var item in NewChildObjectsList)
{
    Parent.Childs.Add(item);
}
Update(Parent); // Add new list then update
```